# RecyclerView + SQLite - removing row from Database and calling .notifyItemRemoved re-adds the row temporarily at the bottom

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a RecyclerView which gets the data out of a SQLite Database Cursor without storing the data in an ArrayList before.

I try to delete a row at a given position on Button click, but it immediatly re-adds the row at the bottom of the RecyclerView. When i close and re-open the Activity however, the entry is gone (as i want it). Also when i try to click the re-added entry, i get an Exception, so it seems to be not there anymore.

I googled for a while but i couldnt find an answer. Does it have to do with the Cursor? Do i have to provide a new Cursor to the Adapter after removing a row from the Table? If yes, how?

This is my code:

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mDeleteImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_delete);

        [...]

        mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = new MySQLiteHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + MyContract.MyEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    database.delete(MyContract.MyEntry.TABLE_NAME, MyContract.MyEntry._ID + "=?", new String[] {cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyContract.MyEntry._ID))});
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are thinking that you need to update the cursor. Yes, you will need to because `notifyItemRemoved(position)` will remove the entry from local list. But as you try to scroll data will be fetched from the cursor and it will find the data into the `cursor`.

The way you are setting the cursor initially into your adapter is the same way you will have to update the cursor **or** you can use the `swapCursor` or `changeCursor` method and call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

For more help on cursor with `RecyclerView`, Please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But i dont use the CursorAdapter, so i dont have a swapCursor method. Isnt this CursorAdapter only for ListViews?
I tried to provide a new Cursor over a method but it didnt work.

Comment: Is that custom recyclerview adapter?

Comment: Yes. I tried setting mCursor to a new Cursor but it didnt work. The way i initialy provide the Cursor is over the Adapter's Constructor.

Comment: Right, custom recyclerview adapter

Comment: For more help on cursor with recyclerview, Please take a look at this https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Comment: Somehow it starts working from click 2 onwards, but not for the first click. Weird..
Edit: I know why, because i create the cursor before removing the entry. It works if i create a 2nd cursor after deleting, but i dont know if thats a good approach

Comment: Because on 2nd click it must be refreshing the data again.

Comment: The link doesnt really help because he has a lot of stuff in it i dont understand yet.

Comment: That link gives the full implementation of how to use cursor with recyclerview

Comment: Yes, its the Adapter. But my problem also lays outside of the adapter.

Comment: Actually with cursor you will need to reset the data. as DB has changed and cursor needs to be updated in Adapter. So you will adapter's cursor to be updated.